# leading space lost while using readYaml and writeYaml jenkins utilities

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to update a YAML file using the readYaml and writeYaml jenkins Utilities
As you probably noticed the leading space is lost on the updated file and this makes the YAML file wrong?
How can we make this right ?

```
def yamlDev = readYaml file: "requirements.yaml"
yamlDev.dependencies.each{
        if (it.name.equals('value'))
              it.version = "\"<=${Version.toString()}\""
}
sh "rm requirements.yaml" 
writeYaml file: 'requirements.yaml', data: yamlDev
```

initial YAML file

```
dependencies:
  - name: value
    version: "<= 20.0.x"
```

updated YAML file

```
dependencies
- name: value
  version: <= 20.0.x
```

Comment: I don't believe that makes the yaml wrong... They're the same aren't they?

Comment: i need two spaces before the first key name (precisely before the dash) and they aren't the same

Comment: Yes, but in yaml, those are both describing the same thing.  Parsing both files will end with the same result

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to add that leading white space to the updated Yaml file for a special use case